# toHaveBeenCalled() not working correctly Angular Unit Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular11

I have following object in my angular component:

```
let _user = {user: { id: 1 } };

ngOnInit(){
   if(Object.keys(_user.user).length > 0){
       callSomething()
   }
}
```

=> now for that component spec.ts file

```
describe("",() => {
    let _user = { user: {id: 1} };   
    let component: TempComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TempComponent>;
  
    beforeEach(() => {
         ... component configuration

         fixture.detectChanges(); 
         // this will call lifecycle methods and from there component's callSomething() will also get called.
    });

    it("should not call callSomething() if user properties == 0", () => {
        delete _user.user["id"];
        // now _user will be only { user: {} }

        component.ngOnInit(); // or can call fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component.callSomething).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        // as now the user object will be empty, but because of beforeEach's detectChanges call, it is failing.
    });
});
```

Problem:

Here, when I run the test case it fails saying

> Expected spy not to have been called.

with debugging, I figured out that it is failing because initially from **fixture.detectChanges()** ngOnInit called from there based on the condition **callSomething()** also got called.

So, when the testcase runs it has already called callSomething(). So, it is failing.

What shall I do, to test the case properly?

Comment: I think you need to reset the spy, try resetting using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54419453/7365461. I think you should reset spies in a `beforeEach` so it becomes easier to manage.

Comment: `delete _user.user["id"]` is interfering directly with the component class. Under what circumstances of _actual use_ might that happen? Also you shouldn't spy on the thing you're supposed to be testing; what does `callSomething` _do_? As above you can reset the mock to assert that the method isn't called _again_, but to test the case properly more changes are needed (and we'd need more context to provide detail on what they'd be).

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
If I don't spy on user object then, how can I change it's value? and how can I check the possibilities of other test cases? (ex: keys.length > 0, keys.length < 0, keys.length = 0)

Comment: Again, under what circumstances of actual use might that happen? What does call something really do? Without a [mre] of the component, we can't tell you how to actually test it. But .length < 0 isn't a sensible case, what would a negative length _mean_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Circumstance: if user clears the session, the user id will also get removed. callSomething(): it will reset the states and redirect to the home page

Comment: [Edit] the question to provide a [mre] and the context. The Angular docs show how to test things like components that use the router, read the section on testing: https://angular.io/guide/testing. Let callSomething do its job, rather than spying on it, then test that the job was done, rather than that the method was called.

Comment: thanks, I will check that. @jonrsharpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AliF50 suggested in question's comment, resting the calls of the method worked for me.
[stackoverflow.com/a/54419453/7365461.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/54419453/7365461.)

**Solution:**

```
it("should not call callSomething() if user properties == 0", () => {
  
        component.callSomethig.calls.reset(); 
       // Note: callSomething should be part of spy object. Then only `calls` property will be applied to it.

        delete _user.user["id"];
        component.ngOnInit();
        expect(component.callSomething).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```